# Set RadListView ItemTemplate to transparant on ios

Tags: telerik, nativescript

I have troubles making a RadListView ItemTemplate transparant. I tried to make every element in the xml transparant but nothing works.

I also tried this code, but it isn't transparant, its just light red.

Xml Code

```
<lv:RadListView 
    ...
    itemLoading="onItemLoading"
    backgroundColor="transparent">

    <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout backgroundColor="transparent">
        <lv:ListViewLinearLayout itemInsertAnimation="Default" itemDeleteAnimation="Default" backgroundColor="transparent" />
    </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>

    <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate backgroundColor="transparent">
        ...
    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>

    <lv:RadListView.itemSwipeTemplate backgroundColor="transparent">
        ...
    </lv:RadListView.itemSwipeTemplate>
</lv:RadListView>
```

Javascript code

```
exports.onItemLoading = function(args){
    if(page.ios){
        args.view.backgroundColor = new colorModule.Color(20,255,0,0);
    }
};
```

When i swipe the item to the left or to the right, i can see a part of the background.

---

**Question**: How can i remove the 'default' white background from the RadListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my question.

The problem was that i needed to set the backgroundColor of the backgroundView instead of the view in iOS.

```
exports.onItemLoading = function(args){
    if(page.ios){
        args.ios.backgroundView.backgroundColor = new colorModule.Color(20,255,0,0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you also set the `background-color` of the RadListView to `"transparent"` in CSS.

```
<lv:RadListView
  backgroundColor="transparent"
  ...
</lv:RadListView>
```

You can see an example of a RadListView with a transparent background in the Groceries sample for reference https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries.

Comment: Maybe i was't clear enough about the 'i tried to make every element transparent', but i changed the code to show you what i tried. This answer doesn't solve the problem.